# Chat on mobile device - Link doesn't open in new tab

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks, mobile-web

Can we make it so that clicking a link in chat on a mobile device opens the link in a new tab, instead of the active tab?

If I make my browser request the desktop version links get opened in a new tab.